# Top 10 scores for game leaderboard dynamoDB nodejs sdk query

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, leaderboard

I have a dynamodb which has following fields -

```
id (primary key) (string)
name (user name) (string)
score (sort key) (number)
player (type - regular/new etc.) (string)
```

I'm just trying to get top 10 scores from the DB.
Tried several queries following the documentation by AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property

Here is my query code -

```
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

function getItems(){
  var params = {
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
   ":v1": {
     S: "regular"
    }
  }, 
  KeyConditionExpression: "player = :v1", 
  TableName: "cloudtag_result"
 };
 return ddb.scan(params).promise();
}
```

but it's giving me following error

```
2021-08-21T08:36:43.092Z    1bbd5490-4248-4f06-94ea-724e6d23dac5    ERROR   ValidationException: Query condition missed key schema element: id
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: 2021-08-21T08:36:43.031Z,
  requestId: 'JH91VON2KGVNP7HF41VCBELTUVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 47.72972319109784
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a **Global Secondary Index (GSI)** for this.

Take `player` as your **GSI Partition Key** and `score` as your **GSI Sort Key**, you could actually perform `query` against this **GSI** by providing the value for `player` and use `scanIndexForward (true/false)` for getting the data in ascending or descending order based on the **GSI Sort Key**.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

However, when your data grows bigger, you would probably hit `Hot Partition` problem on your **GSI** which is due to the **GSI Partition Key** that is too much concentrated on a specify key such as `regular`. Therefore, it would be better if you could start doing partition key sharding which you can add a suffix to your `player` such as `regular#1, regular#2... regular#n`. In this way, you would be able to avoid from `Hot Partition` problem.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html

Again, if you adopt this solution, you would need to do a `n times` of queries on the `GSI` to get the top few scorers in each partition due to the partition key sharding and only then you will use code to do the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB has the fundamental limitation that you absolutely have to specify the partition key (or primary key as you call it) in all queries. And it has to be an exact match for what's in the table, no "fuzzy" querying allowed.

You query on `player = ..`, and you don't specify the id. There's no way to make that work in dynamo, you need to specify the primary key.

If your access patterns requires you to be able to look up by player name, you need to have the player name in a PK or a SK, or else you need to do the filtering in your app instead of on the dynamodb server.

You probably want what's called a "single table design". This talk by Rich Houlihan comes highly recommended for anyone doing data modelling with dynamo :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k